# Can't give access rights to libusb with udev rules

Tags: debian, usb, udev

I'm trying to get `OWPDK` (a 1-wire library) to access an USB to 1-wire adapter (DS9490R, based on the DS2490 USB-to-1-wire bridge chip).

This library uses libusb to enumerate devices (using `usb_get_busses`, then exploring `bus->devices` for each bus). It will then get the first device that matches vendor and product ID (I only have one plugged in), and call `usb_open` on it, and then `usb_set_configuration` on the returned handle.

On my Debian 10 system, when I run this program as root, it works fine.

However, I'd like to run the program as user `onewire` from group `onewire` which would get access only to this USB device.

So, I created this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-onewire.rules` which contains this single line :

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{vendor}=="04fa", GROUP="onewire", MODE="0660"
```

I then reload rules with `sudo udevadm control --reload`

While `usb_open` works for that user, `usb_set_configuration` doesn't (returns a non-zero result).

I've tried various combinations in the rule, such as `SUBSYSTEM` (without S), removing the ATTRS condition, etc, with no luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

[The `usb_set_configuration(3)` man page](https://nxmnpg.lemoda.net/3/usb_set_configuration) says:

> int libusb_set_configuration(libusb_device_handle *devh, int config)
>
> Set the active configuration to config for the device contained by devh. This function returns 0 on success, LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND if the requested configuration does not exist, LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY if the interfaces are currently claimed, LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE if the device has been disconnected and a LIBUSB_ERROR code on failure.

So, which non-zero result are you getting?

If there is a kernel driver for the adapter, you'll get `LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY`.

In that case, you (or the library) will need to detach it first. The library can do it automatically if `libusb_set_auto_detach_kernel_driver(handle, 1)` is set (it might be the default), but probably requires being root to do it successfully.

You might need to blacklist the `ds2490` kernel module to prevent it from claiming the 1-wire adapter, if you want the `onewire` user to have `libusb` access to it. Create a file named `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-1wire.conf` with the following contents:

```
blacklist ds2490
```

Then run `modprobe -r ds2490` as root, or reboot.

Comment: `usb_set_configuration` returns `-1`. However I don't know if that's `LIBUSB_ERROR_BUSY` or something else, because that symbol is undeclared. I also tried `USB_ERROR_BUSY`, undeclared as well. I also didn't find either in any `*.h` file on my whole system. `usb_set_configuration` is declared in `/usr/include/usb.h` but I don't see any error code defined there.

Comment: I also get the same error code (`-1`) after blacklisting ds2490 and rebooting.

Comment: In Debian 10, there are 2 versions of `libusb` available, and each has its corresponding development package: `libusb-1.0-0-dev` for `libusb-1.0-0` and `libusb-dev` for `libusb-0.1-4`. The respective `.h` files are at `/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h` and `/usr/include/usb.h`, but only if the development packages are installed.